# Delete row in database by ajax call

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have ajax call where I will pass value to back-end

I need to find data in database  by this value and then delete it

I write this code on back-end

```
 public ActionResult DeletingInternal(string title)
    {

        var item = db.Appointments.Where(x => x.Title == title)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                title = x.Title
            }).FirstOrDefault();
        db.Appointments.Remove(item);

    }
```

But in this row `db.Appointments.Remove(item);` I have error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from '' to 'RS_Main.Models.Appointment'    RS_Main C:\Users\nemes\Source\Repos\RIS_Project_New\RS_Main\Controllers\CalendarController.cs   28  Active

How I can delete row from database?

Comment: Just delete the `.Select(x => new { title = x.Title })` bit - `var item = db.Appointments.Where(x => x.Title == title).FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `db.remove` function you need exact object representing the table, so you dont need select

```
 public ActionResult DeletingInternal(string title)
    {

        var item = db.Appointments.Where(x => x.Title == title).FirstOrDefault();

    db.Appointments.Remove(item);

    db.SaveChanges(); // this saves the changes

}
```

And while using string change it into lowercase or to upper case for better performance.

```
db.Appointments.Where(x => x.Title.ToLower() == title.ToLower() ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db.Appointments.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Title == title).Remove();
db.SaveChanges();
```